# UIViewController addChild and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I see some weird behavior concerning translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints when using addChild.

I created a UITableViewController programmatically, put it inside a UINavigationController, also created programmatically, so no storyboards or anything like that involved. Then, when I added the navigation controller as a child, everything worked perfectly. See here the code I used:

```
    //Add Child View Controller
    self.addChild(viewController)

    //Add Child View as Subview
    self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
    
    print("TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: \(viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)")

    //Define Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        viewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        viewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        viewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
    ])

    //Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Then I discovered I actually didn't need the navigationController, so I just added my tableviewcontroller itself as a child. Suddenly, it didn't work anymore, and I saw an empty screen. I printed out the frame, which was 0,0,0,0.
Then, I remembered that when I use 'NSLayoutConstraint.activate', I need to set 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' to false.

So I did, and, like I expected, it worked again. But it felt strange to me, because as far as I knew, UINavigationControllers didn't automatically set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false. So I put it back into the navigation controller and printed out the value for translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, and to my surprise, the value showed said it was set to **true**! But somehow it still works and I see the tableviewcontroller perfectly!

I also printed out the value of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in viewDidAppear and other places, but everywhere the printed value is **true**.
Does UINavigationController magically do some stuff somewhere?

Comment: You should show a [mcve] for 3 and 4. Did you also add constraints to the view in the storyboard? If not, I don't see why this is unexpected.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your reply. I can create a minimal example, but I was hoping I was just missing something. As for the storyboard, no I didn't make any constraints. But why do you say it's as you expect? I thought the storyboard one would automatically set it to false, but apparently, as I print it out, it's not the case. But it still works somehow...

Comment: You only need `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be false when you add AutloLayout constraints. It is true by default, and the storyboard sets it to false when you add constraints on the storyboard. If there are no constraints, and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` *should* be true.

Comment: But I DO add constraints as you can see in my code.

Comment: I thought we are talking about the storyboard? Are you using both at the same time? This is why a [mcve] is important.

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate your comments, but maybe my question was not clear. Here is another try:
After I remembered I had to set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, I just wanted to see what would happen if I created it inside storyboard AND what would happen if I put it inside a navigation controller. But for both of these, I still used the same code, including setting constraints, to finally add it as a child. That's why I think it's strange that it worked for both, even though in both cases the printed value for translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints was true.

Comment: @BobdeGraaf Try printing `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in `viewDidAppear`. What do you get?

Comment: @HangarRash good question, but still true! Also, I've edited the question to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: @Sweeper, I've edited the question to make it more clear, perhaps this helps?

Comment: @BobdeGraaf - in your code snippet, is `viewController` a `UINavigationController`? If you don't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` do you get auto-layout warnings/errors in the debug console?